# Vertical areas along with line on the chart - is that possible

Tags: highcharts

I need to make chart that representing months for x axis and amounts of money for y.
It is very easy with highcharts library to draw the line diagram. The problem is that the designer wants each month to have a vertical column which changes its color when hovering above it.
(like in the attached pic)
[image]

Is there easy way to achieve this?
Thanks forwards

Answer (score 1):

It would require to use [point.events.mouseOver](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver).

There you would need to get actual month (use `this.point.x` or `this.x` to assume which month is active) and then add new plotBand using [xAxis.addPlotBand()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotBand%28%29). Of course you need to remove previous plotBand also.